# Not able to read the Mobile number from a webpage

Tags: watir

Today I have come across an interesting question in stackoverflow in the side of Java Selenium Binding, I am trying to find a solution through WATIR but I couldn't succeed here,

I try to read the mobile number from a page and here is the webpage

```
<span class="telnowpr">
<a class="tel mtel">
<span class="mobilesv icon-ba"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ts"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-oqp"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-wx"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-nlm"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ts"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-fde"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-fde"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-nlm"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-lk"/>
</a>
,
<a class="tel mtel">
<span class="mobilesv icon-ba"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ts"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-oqp"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-wx"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-nlm"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ts"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ji"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-fde"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-fde"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-nlm"/>
<span class="mobilesv icon-ikj"/>
</a>
</span>
```

Each and every span is holding a single number which I can see when move the firebug tool arrow but no number is inside the span in html but however it's appearing in the page. I tried to extract through value and also text but no suceess so far, I haven't seen pages like this so far.

Code

```
b = Watir::Browser.new @driver

b.goto 'https://www.justdial.com/Ahmedabad/Knife-Fork-Restaurant-Shah-E-Alam-Tollnaka-Opposite-Swaminarayan-College-Shah-Alam/079PXX79-XX79-170524174654-D3J2_BZDET?xid=QWhtZWRhYmFkIEFmZ2hhbmkgUmVzdGF1cmFudHM='

p b.span(class: 'telnowpr').text
```

which actually prints a comma, this prints a comma because comma appears between two `<a>` but I don't how to bring out all the numbers. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using icons to display the numbers instead of just numbers. I presume it is to prevent bots and automated software from collecting all of the numbers for spam.

Each number appears to have a unique css class, so why don't you create a function that will check the text in the class and return the number it corresponds to?

Comment: Hi, thanks yes it appears that way. Please include the code which expresses your idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
List<WebElement> allSpans = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#comp-contact span.telnowpr >a > span.icon-acb"));

System.out.println(allSpans.size());
//for(WebElement item : allSpans) {
        String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('ul#comp-contact span.telnowpr >a > span.icon-acb'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')";
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String content = (String) js.executeScript(script);
        System.out.println("Value : " + content);
//}
```

this is for a single span element shown in below image, You'll need to to do it for all `<span>` elements under

```
<ul id="comp-contact">
```

[image] :

Comment: Hi Thank you very much, It's very late night here, Please give me tommorrow end of the day, I will convert this into Ruby code and let you know. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Hi, I am receiving this error `Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.`

Comment: @Rajagopalan : it does-nt work properly, but it doesn't give error.

Comment: It's giving me this error, I executed your as it is in Java Selenium binding and also WATIR(wrapper around ruby selenium binding), it is giving me the same error in both the places.